# Handling Input in GLFW for a Small Engine

Tags: c++, opengl, input, glfw, glew

Working on a small engine using [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com/), but after a while, I still couldn't figure out the best way to handle input.

Sure, I could follow the guide and used their function:

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

But, I'm looking for a simpler approach:

```
if(key_a.isPressed)
{
    ...
}
```

Another challenge is being able to use that code in different areas of the class instead of shoving all the input into that key_callback function.

*I'm fairly new to C++, maybe only  a few months experience, but I'm definitely not new to it*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [glfwGetKey](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gadd341da06bc8d418b4dc3a3518af9ad2) to get the state of a specific key.

```
int state = glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A);
```

Comment: Note that, unless you have activated GLFW's sticky keys mode, you may miss key presses if the key is pressed and released fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how i have done it in the past.

```cpp
int main(){
    ...
    glfwSetKeyCallback(glfwWindow, Input::KeyCallback);
    Input::IsPressed(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)
    ...
}

class Input {
private:
    static std::vector<int> Input::m_pressed(400,0);
public:
    static void Input::KeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        Input::m_pressed[key] = action;
    }
    static bool Input::IsPressed(int key)
    {
        return (bool)Input::m_pressed[key];
    }
}
```